# can we Trigger dataflow jobs only once from cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

My BigQuery table is being loaded with multiple batch jobs, resulting in creating multiple log entries in stackdriver logging. I want to use these log entries to trigger dataflow job by sending them to pubsub topic and then using cloud function to run the dataflow job.

The issue, we have more than 1 batch job and therefore more than 1 log entries going to pubsub topic and cloud function trying to run same dataflow job again and again.

I need solution that runs dataflow job once when all the batch jobs completes data loading in bigQuery table. (Number of batch jobs is not constant)

Comment: Maybe an easier solution would be using Airflow DAGs to trigger everything, have you consider them?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but could you use streaming Daaflow jobs that would just process records as they're received, instead of triggering jobs with functions?

Comment: Before starting to perform several load job, do you know (and can you trace somewhere) the number of job that you will launch? Else, do you know the batch job duration and the max duration between the end of the 1st job and the last one?

Comment: @guillaume, we are trying to post one message on pubsub after the batch job completion (which will help us to skip SD logging) and eventually trigger downstream functionality, lets see how it goes